# Please identify this game from movie Dawn of the dead aka "Zombie"

Tags: identify-this-game

I have identified 5 of the 6 games on the movie "Zombie" of George Romero (the scene of video-game playing at minute 01:18:00).

The titles are:

```
Qwak Atari 1974
Gangbusters, Midway 1974
Night Driver Micronetics/Atari 1976
F1 Atari Namco 1976(first version electro-mechanic)
Gunfight, Midway 1975
```

I miss the last one.

I have two screenshots of it

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: can you tell which the other ones are? and are you sure of the english title?

Comment: I will tell the other ones after 10-20 minutes

Comment: I'm searching on google, "old videogame shooting flyng saucers, shooting ufo, but the game don't appear

Comment: Making search of ufo games in the 70s i found only one title "ufo chase" electra 1975, but no screens are present

Comment: Was there a Start Trek game? What is that object on the top left that looks like some variant of a Federation craft?

Comment: I'm searching for Star trek game, i found one of 1972 but the shoots are totally different from this one

Comment: Since OP never answered about the title: It is [_Dawn of the Dead_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077402) which was released under the name _Zombie_ in a few markets.

Comment: I will correct now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Starship 1**, Atari, 1977

Hope that helps :)

[image]

Comment: damn I checked a YT channel for all 70 games (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFDFBD60F167A0BB6) and didn't notice it. It was there (screen of the question is reversed): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWMf-TSWxsM&list=PLFDFBD60F167A0BB6&index=71&ab_channel=OldClassicRetroGaming

Comment: I remember seeing that game at Midwest Gaming Classic, but I don't remeber the planets being that clear.  The monitor wasn't in super sharp focus; I'm not sure if that's because of age, or becasue blurriness helped make the graphics look less pixelated.  I'm somewhat curious what sort of hardware would have been used for the planets.  Perhaps there was a RAM with two bytes per scan line to give the start and ending pixel of the planet on that scan line?

Comment: Maybe make a new question for that if you want to know @supercat ? :D I was surprised to see the planets' texture not move along with the planet on screen. It's like the planets are windows into a fixed pattern (which I would expect to be implemented as a muddled up bitwise op on the outputs of the current X and Y counters of the screen as it's being rendered)